# How to trigger clean method from model when updating?

Tags: django, django-models

When I  save my form I perform validation of data that is defined in my model

```
    def clean(self):
    model = self.__class__
    if self.unit and (self.is_active == True)  and model.objects.filter(unit=self.unit, is_terminated = False , is_active = True).exclude(id=self.id).count() > 0:
        raise ValidationError('Unit has active lease already, Terminate existing one prior to creation of new one or create a not active lease '.format(self.unit))
```

How can I trigger same clean method during simple update without a need to duplicate clean logic in my update view?(In my view I just perform update without any form)

```
Unit.objects.filter(pk=term.id).update(is_active=False)
```

Comment: You can't possibly do this when calling `update`, as that happens directly in the database without loading the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` don't call the `save` method of your model and so it's not possible for django to raise `ValidationError` exceptions in this case.

You need to at least call the `full_clean` method of your model before doing the update.

Maybe like this ?

```
unit = Unit.objects.get(pk=term.id)
unit.is_active = False    

try:
    unit.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Handle the exceptions here

unit.save()
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects